# The system cannot find the file specified- Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have batch script file, which should encrypt a file with pgp. I have defined a task in task scheduler to do this, but I am keep receiving the error"The system cannot find the file specified".

Interestingly, when I run the same line of script in my powershell , the encrypted file is successfully generated.

I was wondering if anyone knows what can possibly be wrong here?

I tried to give the full path in my batch script , and also added the pass in start in part, when defining the action.

the batch scrip code is here::

```
rem @echo off 
@set path=c:\test;%path%

@set d=%date:~-4,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~-7,2% 
@set d=%d: =_% 
@set t=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2% @set t=%t: =0%

Rem  Generate PGP encrypted file 
@echo Starting PGP... >> c:\apps\ftpLogs\test.log 
gpg2 --batch --yes -r testkey --output c:\test\foo\test_20150505.pgp --encrypt c:\test\foo\test_20150505.txt >> c:\apps\ftpLogs\test.log
```

and the script that I ran in my powershell, which works fine, is this line:

```
gpg2 --batch --yes -r testkey --output c:\test\foo\test_20150505.pgp --encrypt c:\test\foo\test_20150505.txt >> c:\apps\ftpLogs\test.log
```

Comment: Please post your code so that we can actually see what the problem is instead of just guessing.

Comment: Your powershell one-liner that contained a batch variable (`%d%`) worked properly? Really?

Comment: oh no, I copied the old version of both in both I added the date. let me fix the code for you.

Comment: Corrected, this is the one which is not working now!

Comment: If your PowerShell version works, why not use that from your scheduled task?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician what do you mean to use that? Could you please tell me more about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve the issue. The problem was with the user authority. The batch script was suppose to encrypt a file and then ftp the encrypted file to the vendor's ftp server.

Apparently in Windows Server 2012 , the ADMINISTRATORS have the permission to create a file (here the encrypted file) while this user does not have the permission to send it. and SYSTEM user has the permission to send but not to create. (Both of them had this authority back in Win Server 2012).

So what did I do at the end, was to make two different batch script tasks and schedule them with 10 mins time distance. The first one was running the above code with ADMINISTRATOR privileges and the second one was sending it out with SYSTEMS.

Answer (score 0):

If your batch file doesn't work, but the PowerShell script does, just run the PowerShell script from your scheduled task instead.

From the Scheduled Task, instead of entering the path to your batch file specify PowerShell.exe (or more likely C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe). Then in the Arguments box specify your parameters. You probably want to hide the window, so we'll include that in the arguments, and for this you can probably skip loading a profile, so we'll add that too. Then just use the `-Command` parameter to specify your code that you have in the question.

So your Program to run box should show:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe
```

Then the box that says "Add Arguments (optional)" should have:

```
-NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -command "gpg2 --batch --yes -r testkey --output c:\test\foo\test_$((get-date).ToString(yyyyMMdd)).pgp --encrypt c:\test\foo\test_$((get-date).ToString(yyyyMMdd)).txt >> c:\apps\ftpLogs\test.log"
```

On a side note, should that be gpg2 or pgp2? I just copied your command, but it seemed odd to me that they would name it like that.